# Mastery over the groups $S_n,A_n,D_n$ and $Q_8$

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, quaternions, dihedral-groups, permutation-cycles

I am a graduate student and currently preparing for PHD entrance in the leading institutes of India. For that I have to strengthen my group theory. But I must admit that I have a shaky foundation in group theory, specially the symmetric group, alternating group, dihedral group and quaternion group.

I do not have clear idea about the structure of these groups. I want some information about them, for example center, normal subgroups, Cayley digraph and subgroup lattice.

Can someone suggest me some book or note where I can find all these details? Also one can suggest me some notes or stack exchange pages for the same purpose.

Comment: $S_n$'s only (proper, nontrivial) normal subgroup of $A_n$, which is simple. Their subgroup lattice is wildly impossible for humans to describe for arbitrary $n$. You should find all these features for dihedral groups and the quaternion group as a good exercise (googling yields quick answers too). The Cayley graphs of $S_n$ and $A_n$ depends on choice of generating set, of which many studied ones are available to choose from, though I haven't studied these graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) Pick a standard book like :

1. Topics in Algebra  by I. N. Herstein
2. Abstract Algebra
   Book by Dummit,Foote
3. Algebra
   Book by Thomas W. Hungerford
4. Algebra : A Graduate Course Book by Martin Isaacs

B) [Expository papers](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/) by Keith Conard. (One of best resources on the web)

C) [Group Explorer](https://nathancarter.github.io/group-explorer/GroupExplorer.html) by Nathan Carter. ( Structure of finite groups of small order)

D) Search on Wikipedia by topic.

E) Finally MSE when you stuck.